# MDX Query Performance :

Tags: ssas, mdx

I trying to execute below MDX query it took more than 10 mins is there any possibility to improve performance on below query.

```
WITH 
MEMBER PatientName AS [DimPatient].[Full Name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
MEMBER PatientAge AS [DimPatient].[Age].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
MEMBER PatientGender AS [DimPatient].[Gender].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
MEMBER PatientMRN AS [DimPatient].[Medical Record Number].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
MEMBER [PCPList] AS Generate ([DimPCP].[Provider Key].[Provider Key].MEMBERS,
    IIF([Measures].[CCMPatientCnt] <> 0,[DimPCP].[Provider Key].CurrentMember.Member_Caption + '',NULL))
MEMBER CareTeamList AS [DimCareTeam].[CareTeamName].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 

MEMBER  ConditionList AS [DimCondition].[Condition Name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 

SELECT  ORDER(NonEmpty (([DimPatient].[Patient Key].[Patient Key],
                         [DimCareTeam].[CareTeamName].[CareTeamName],
                         [DimCondition].[Condition Name].[Condition Name]),
                        {[Measures].[CCMPatientCnt]} ),
             ([Measures].[patientName]),BASC) ON 1 ,
{ [Measures].[PatientName] ,
  [Measures].[PatientAge] ,
  [Measures].[PatientGender] ,
  [Measures].[PatientMRN] ,
  [Measures].[Num Of Minutes] ,
  [PCPList] ,[CareTeamList] ,
  [ConditionList] }   ON 0 
FROM [NavigateCube] 
WHERE ( [DimManagedPopulation].[ManagedPopulationKey].&[4332],
        [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20180731])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZUM7.png)

Comment: Can you show some of the results please, I think all those member_captions will slow things up

Comment: @whytheq, yes the performance impact on ConditionList member_captions, the conditions are more for each patient. even I changed the conditions to comma separated for each patient. a little bit is good for performance is there any suggests to improve query performance. for sample data go through the line https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFxsi.png

Comment: Have you tried it without the ORDER, to see if that makes it faster?